# Is it possible to create a User Defined Variable in JMeter using an expression?

Tags: performance, testing, jenkins, jmeter

I've been trying to use [JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) to create some automated Performance Tests and I'm setting up a job in Jenkins so that people can run it and view the results there.

I'm trying to add a few parameters to the job that correspond to the options available in the Thread Group. They are:

- Number of Users
- Ramp-up Period
- Loop count

Some people don't quite understand the concept of the 'Ramp-up Period' so instead I wanted to make refer to it as 'Delay' and use it to control how long each thread will wait before starting the test. This would mean that the 'Ramp-up Period' should be equal to (The Number of Users x Delay).

The command I'm using to run the test is below:

```
jmeter -n -t <myscript>.jmx -l results.jtl -j jmeter.log -JUSERS=10 -JDELAY=1 -JLOOPS=1
```

and the variables look like this:

```
USERS = ${__P(USERS)}
RAMPUP = ${USERS}*${__P(DELAY)}
LOOPS = ${__P(LOOPS)}
```

But unfortunately the value of the RAMPUP variable was not what I expected. It ended up being "${USERS}*1"

Is there a way to do this in JMeter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JMeter variables and properties are Strings, you can not apply arithmetic operations to them. The behavior you're getting is absolutely expected. Also there is no possibility to dynamically change properties during runtime, you'll have to calculate ramp-up prior to passing it to JMeter.

Answer (score 0):

You can add BSF PreProcessor before you test plan, calculate there values for user defined variables and put values into variables using [putObject(String key,Object value)](http://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html#putObject%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29)